# Where can I find the commentary on nAtya shAstra (abhinavabharati)?

Tags: resource, abhinavagupta, natya-shastra

Bhagwan Sri Abhinavagupta's most important work on the philosophy of art is Abhinavabhāratī – a long and complex commentary on Natya Shastra of Bharata Muni. This work has been one of the most important factors contributing to Abhinavagupta's fame up until present day.

Can I find an online version or a printed version?

Does this book have any translation ?

Comment: But I'm curious to know why you want it? I think it's based on drama only. Right?

Comment: it has whole of performing arts including music which is spiritual music

Comment: There seems to be one chapter online here http://www.columbia.edu/~aso2101/projects/abhinavabharati/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are all three volumes of Abhinavagupta's commentary in Sanskrit, in PDF format:

[Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/NatyaShastraOfBharatamuniVolIK.Krishnamoorthy)

[Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/NatyaShastraOfBharatamuniVolIILateM.RamakrishnaKavi)

[Volume 3](https://archive.org/details/NatyaShastraWithTheCommentaryOfAbhinavaguptaVol.IIIM.RamakrishnaKavi)

It has been translated into English, but it's not available online.  It is available in print form though, [here](https://www.amazon.in/Natyasastra-Bharatamuni-Commentary-Abhinavbharati-Translation/dp/8183150446).